# vb.net function File.txt saved in a-z 0-1 order

Tags: vb.net, function, file, sorting

I have a function,
 I want the lines to be saved in order;

- A/Z
- 0/9990 periodic

Hi everyone, thank you in advance.

My function is this;

```
Dim WorksList As String = "c:\db\works.txt"

Public Function WorksListSave()
   Dim wl As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
   For Each o As Object In ComboBox_WorkName.Items
       wl.AppendLine(o)
   Next

   File.WriteAllText(WorksList, wl.ToString())

   Return False

End Function
```

Comment: Your code makes no effort to sort the lines. What have you tried so far to do so? And why don't you just let the combobox sort them for you?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your logic to compare your strings in a function like this:

```
 Private Function MyComparer(x As String, y As String) As Integer
    ' TODO: Add tules compare x to y.
    ' if x > y then return 1
    ' if x = y then return 0
    ' if x < y then return -1
End Function
```

First convert your items to a List(of String)

```
Dim MyList As List(Of String) = (From obj In ComboBox_WorkName.Items Select CStr(obj)).ToList()
```

Then  `Sort` the list using your comparer:

```
MyList.Sort(AddressOf MyComparer)
```

The write your list to your file:

```
File.WriteAllLines(WorksList, MyList)
```

Comment: I thank you for the fast answer, I did as you say but it does not work, maybe I'm wrong, can you make a more concrete example to use? thank you!

Comment: Gravity Code Description File Project Line Elimination Status
Error BC30456 'Select' is not a member of 'ComboBox.ObjectCollection'

Comment: Add a reference to `System.Linq`

Comment: Tnx @Alexander

My reference:
`Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Linq`

The error persists

**Gravity Code Description File Project Line Elimination Status Error BC30456 'Select' is not a member of 'ComboBox.ObjectCollection'**

Comment: You can rewrite it like this  `Dim MyList As List(Of String) = (From obj In ComboBox_WorkName.Items Select CStr(obj)).ToList()`